# Move data from azure blob storage to SharePoint Online library

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, spfx

Could you please advise me how to move data from azure blob storage to SharePoint Online document library by Azure Function Apps ( with out logic apps)

Answer (score 1):

Azure Functions 2.0 supports PowerShell so that may be the easiest way to do it without having to write a full code. The logic should be straight forward. Similar to the logic here - http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/03/copy-files-between-document-libraries-using-powershell-in-sharepoint.html  only that the source will be Azure blob

You should be able to read the files from blob storage account using the URL of the blob storage account. That will be the source URL in the script provided in the above. The destination is SPO.